# recursive function for dynamic multilevel menu php

Tags: php, mysql, function, recursion

I've a `mysql` table structure like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS menu(
id INT(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
p_id INT(5), -- parent id
sort_id INT(5) NOT NULL, -- for position
title VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
etc ...);
```

data structure would be something like this:

```
id | p_id | sort_id | title 
1  | NULL |    1    |  root_1
2  |  1   |    1    |  sub1 of root_1
3  |  1   |    2    |  sub2 of root_1
4  | NULL |    2    |  root_2
5  |  2   |    1    |  sub1 of root_2
6  |  2   |    2    |  sub2 of root_2
7  |  3   |    1    |  sub1 of `sub2 of root_1`
```

I've created a php script to show up one level sub menu, but I can't make up my mind how to get other levels. I think a recursive function is needed, for example, to get `sub1 of sub2 of root_1` element in this task.

If anyone has any idea how to start creating a recursive function in this situation , please advise me, thanks :)

Comment: what happened to the exact question from 60 mins ago? -1 if I could.

Comment: if this question is the same as a previous question, just update the first question

Comment: I've deleted previous and wrote this one , is not it same as update ?

Comment: next time, you can just click "edit" under the tags to update your question

Comment: I already told you that your database design is flawed. but you said it's very good. Sounds like you don't need help.

Comment: @LeonKramer I've said I think it is good , if it is not enough good , what is wrong with it ? how you think it will be better to structure ?

Answer (score 0):

It might be best to first turn this into a tree type structure:

```
Menu Top
  |
Nodes with NULL p_id
  |
Children
```

You could do this by creating a MenuNode class that has an array of children.  You don't have to do it that way, but it will make it much easier to create a recursive function to output the menu.

Answer (score -1):

function generate_menu_list($parent_id) 
{ 
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM menu WHERE p_id ='$parent_id' order by sort_id  ");
    if (result) 
    {
      while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
      {
        $count = mysql_query("SELECT count(0) as cnt FROM menu_master WHERE parent_id='".$row['id']."'");
        $countrow = mysql_fetch_array($count);

```
    echo '<li><a href="'$linktoredirect.'"><span class="fa fa-user"></span>'.$row['title '].'</a> ';

     if($countrow['cnt']>0)
     {
        echo '<ul>'; 
        $this->generate_menu_list($row['id']);  
        echo '</ul>';
     }  
     echo '</li>';
  } 
}
```

}