# Multi-Dimensional Navigation Array

Tags: php, css, html

Trying to construct a navigation using multi-dimensional arrays and recursion.  I have the following code:

First I run `<?php $title = 'pagename'; ?>` on each individual page beneath doctype (for active class detection)

**ARRAY:**

```
<?php

$nav_array = array ('Home' => 'index.php',
                   'About' => array ( 'about.php', array (
                        'Michael' => array( 'michael.php', array (
                            'Blog' => 'blog.php',
                            'Portfolio' => 'portfolio.php')), 
                        'Aaron' => 'aaron.php' , 
                        'Kenny' => 'kenny.php', 
                        'David'=> 'david.php')),

                   'Services' => array ( 'services.php', array (
                        'Get Noticed' => 'getnoticed.php', 
                        'Hosting' => 'hosting.php')),

                   'Clients' => 'clients.php',
                   'Contact Us' => 'contact.php'
    );

    $base = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
?>
```

**FOREACH:** (generates nav)

```
<ul>
<?php

foreach ($nav_array as $k => $v) {
    echo buildLinks ($k, $v, $base);    
}
?>
</ul>
```

**buildLinks:**

```
<?php // Building the links

function buildLinks ($label_name, $file_name, $active_class) {
    if ($label_name == $title) {
        $theLink = "<li><a class=\"selected\" href=\"$file_name\">$label_name</a></li>\n";
    } else {
        $theLink = "<li><a href=\"$file_name\">$label_name</a></li>\n";
    }

    return $theLink;
}


?>
```

**Result:** http://khill.mhostiuckproductions.com/siteLSSBoilerPlate/arraytest.php

The sub menu's will appear on the hover of parent element using CSS.  I need to be able to fall through multiple sub-levels without modifying anything but the array.

How do I make my foreach fall through the rest of the array recursively?

(Note: that I have to have the ability to apply a class of active to current pages, and a class of arrow to parent elements that have a sub-menu present.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No matter what data structure you use to build your navigation, you'll need to make your function recursive, here's a quick and dirty way:

```
echo "<ul>";
foreach ($nav_array as $nav_title => $nav_data) {
  echo buildLinks($nav_title, $nav_data, $base, $title);
}
echo "</ul>";

/* NOTE that we pass $title to the function */
function buildLinks ($label_name, $file_name, $active_class, $title) {

  $theLink = '';
  /* this is dirty code, you should reconsider your data structure */
  $navigation_list = false;
  if (is_array($file_name)) {
    $navigation_list = $file_name[1];
    $file_name = $file_name[0];
  }

  if ($active_class == $title) {
    $theLink = "<li><a class=\"selected\" href=\"$file_name\">$label_name</a></li>\n";
  } else {
    $theLink = "<li><a href=\"$file_name\">$label_name</a></li>\n";
  }

  if ($navigation_list) {
    $theLink .= "<ul>";
    foreach ($navigation_list as $nav_title => $nav_data) {
      $theLink .= buildLinks($nav_title, $nav_data, $active_class, $title);
    }
    $theLink .= "</ul>";
  }

  return $theLink;
}
```

Not a clean solution in anyway, if I were you I'd change the data structure to be an easier one to handle.

Comment: The data structure meaning the array?  Do you have any suggestions as to what path I should take on that?  Something I can search for?

Comment: Sure see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11907790/recursive-function-for-dynamic-multilevel-menu-php

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a very bad way. I recommend to save your menu elements as XML or JSON and use parsers. It will facilitate your work.