# <details> <summary> php code tutorial example: How to retrieve nested master => detail records per php and mysql

Tags: php, html, multi-level, html-tag-details, html-tag-summary

based on Master => Detail relations of mysql fields in a database:

Company - Program - Level

- Adobe - Photoshop - Beginner
- Adobe - Photoshop - Advanced
- Adobe - Illustrator - ....
- ....
- Microsoft - Word - Beginner
- ....
- Microsoft - Excel - ....

I am struggling with the multi-level  -  layouts, also called nested , in HTML5 only without JavaScript.

I want to use an sql String with "Select field1,field2,field3" to display the contents like in a windows-Explorer style.

Perhaps there is a tutorial / Excample out there? so far I have not found a multi-level php script using HTML 5 only without the use of  JavaScript!

Comment: Can you elaborate on the tables and structure of data that exists? Also the structure of data that you need? I'm guessing you might need some kind of recursive function to build a multi-level structure, but it would be helpful to have more info and detail. I'm also not sure exactly what Window Explorer style means. You're looking to create a multi-level menu? [This may be helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11404468/multi-level-menu-with-php-mysql)

Comment: Please share more details. How is this question related to PHP? Without sharing any code, it's impossible to see what you've achieved so far, and where you are stuck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A HTML 5 Solution with  and

```
<style>
details {
    padding: 1px;
    background-color: #f6f7f8;
    margin-bottom: 1px;
}
details[open] {
    /* the style goes here */
}

summary {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.level_0 {
    margin-left: 1em;
    padding-left: 1em;
    color:red;
}
.level_1 {
    margin-left: 2em;
    padding-left: 1em;
    color:green;
}
.level_2 {
    margin-left: 3em;
    padding-left: 1em;
    color:blue;
}
.level_3 {
    margin-left: 4em;
    padding-left: 1em;
    color:gray;
}
</style>
<h4>
<details open>
    <summary  class='level_0'>Microsoft</summary>
    <details>
        <summary class='level_1'>Word</summary>
            <details>
                <summary class='level_2'>Basic</summary>
                    <ul class='level_3'>
                        <li>Module 1</li>
                        <li>Module 2
                    </ul>
            </details>
            <details>
                <summary class='level_2'>Advanced</summary>
                    <ul class='level_3'>
                        <li>Module 3</li>
                        <li>Module 4
                    </ul>
            </details>
    </details>
    <details>
        <summary class='level_1'>Excel</summary>
            <details>
                <summary class='level_2'>Basic</summary>
                    <ul class='level_3'>
                        <li>Module 5</li>
                        <li>Module 6
                    </ul>
            </details>          
    </details>
</details>
<details open'>
    <summary class='level_0'>Adobe</summary>
    <details>
        <summary class='level_1'>Photoshop</summary>
            <details>
                <summary class='level_2'>Basic</summary>
                    <ul class='level_3'>
                        <li>Module 7</li>
                        <li>Module 8
                    </ul>
            </details>
            <details>
                <summary class='level_2'>Advanced</summary>
                    <ul class='level_3'>
                        <li>Module 9</li>
                        <li>Module 10
                    </ul>
            </details>
    </details>
    <details>
        <summary class='level_1'>Illustrator</summary>
            <details>
                <summary class='level_1'>Basic</summary>
                    <ul class='level_3'>
                        <li>Module 11</li>
                        <li>Module 12
                    </ul>
            </details>          
    </details>
</details>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my answer how to create a combination of entries in a three arrays.

```
    <?php
function combinations($arrays, $i = 0) {
    if (!isset($arrays[$i])) {
        return array();
    }
    if ($i == count($arrays) - 1) {
        return $arrays[$i];
    }
    // get combinations from subsequent arrays
    $tmp = combinations($arrays, $i + 1);
    $result = array();
    // concat each array from tmp with each element from $arrays[$i]
    foreach ($arrays[$i] as $v) {
        foreach ($tmp as $t) {
            $result[] = is_array($t) ? 
                array_merge(array($v), $t) :
                array($v, $t);
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
$arrCombi=combinations(
    array(
        array('Microsoft','Adobe','Softskills'), 
        array('Word','Excel','Photoshop','Homeoffice'), 
        array('Grundlagen','Expert')
        )
    );
$line="";
foreach ($arrCombi as $k => $v){
    $line .= "(".implode(" AND ",$v) . ")  OR \n";
}
$line=substr($line, 0, -4);
echo nl2br($line);
echo"<hr><pre>";
print_r(
    combinations(
        array(
            array('Microsoft','Adobe','Softskills'), 
            array('Word','Excel','Photoshop','Homeoffice'), 
            array('Grundlagen','Expert')
        )
    )
);
echo "</pre>";
?>
```